# Basic Rails 3 saving parent object with association object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a basic rails question where I need to save two associated objects.

The association is Rtake has_many :companies and Company belongs_to :rtake

```
def create
  @rtake = RTake.new(:email => params[:contact_email])
  @rtake.role = "PROVIDER"

  @company = @rtake.companies.build(params[:company])
  @company.rtake = @rtake

  respond_to do |format|
    if @company.save_company_and_rtake              
      format.html{ redirect_to admin_companies_url}
    else
      flash.now[:errors] = @company.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
      format.html{ render "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

In my company.rb class I have

```
def save_company_and_rtake
  status1 = self.save(:validate => false)      
  status2 = self.rtake.save(:validate => false)      
  status  = status1 && status2
  status
end
```

The problem I face is that the company.rtake_id remains `nil`. Ideally shouldn't the company.rtake_id get updated to the @rtake.id after save.

I know I am missing something basic. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need this line:

```
@company.rtake = @invitation
```

@invitation is nil from what you've shown .

But also, when you built the `@company`, `@rtake.id` isn't set because it hasn't been saved.

Answer (score 0):

> @company = @rtake.companies.build(params[:company])
>   @company.rtake = @rtake

`@rtake.companies.build(params[:company])` This already means `@company.rtake == @rtake`. it's redundent here.